# How to pass value from subform to mainform ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a subform (Datasheet view form).  When i click a row in subform, i want pass  that row value to text box in main form . In  subform even  wrote this

```
 Private Sub Form_Click()
 MsgBox (Noloan)
 End Sub
```

But i don't know how to pass that subform form_click no_loan to mainform.textbox. Thanks for your help.
Additional data:In my db , i have a table which consist field No,NoLoan,Name. NoLoan Field value as i wanna clicked .From that table i create a subform/datasheet view ,subform name is T_Loan1. Then I create Main Form, name is FindLoan2. In that main/parent form i create text box, called Text7, and put T_Loan1 in subform object at footer.

Comment: Textbox can have an expression that references control in subform. But that is usually done for value calculated in subform. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just pass value in row (one field) that i click in subform(datasheet view) to text box in parent/main form.

Comment: But for what purpose? Are you actually trying to save this value to a field? Why?

Comment: I'm trying to filter table after pass that value

Comment: Try: `Me.Parent.Text7 = Me.ID`.

Comment: Read and learn [this link](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm).

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto to the subform and click on the field which has the row value
2. Select Field property - click on events tab --> On Click --> Code Builder
3. Put below code in the Click event where Form_frmMain is your form name and Me.ID is the field.

---

```
Private Sub ID_Click()
   Forms!FindLoan2.Text7 = Me.ID
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working, error object required. My main form name is FindLoan2 and the text box name is Text7. So i wrote

Comment: Not working, error object required. My main form name is FindLoan2 and the text box name is Text7. So i wrote FindLoan2.Text=Me.Id

Comment: @user3744203 Maybe the field name you are providing is incorrect. What is the name of your field which has row value?

Comment: @user3744203, you should edit question to provide additional info about your db and revised code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

I put this

=[Forms]![FindLoan2]![subformTLOAN].[Form]![Noloan]

in my Text7 Control and It's work.
Thank's for all attention.

Comment: My first comment under question indicated this should be feasible. Can probably simplify to: `[subformTLOAN]![Noloan]`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write code that ignores the forms!names. If you copy the form, or change the sub form, or even drop the sub form into a different form, then all your code breaks.

To reference the textbox in the parent form from code, use:

me.Parent!Text7 = me!id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of MS Access you are using, but it is also possible to use Tempvars to store values for use elsewhere if you have a complicated application which makes referencing another form/field/control difficult.

To create:

```
Tempvars.Add "TempVarName", TempvarValue
```

To use:

```
Tempvars!TempVarName
```

To remove:

```
Tempvars.Remove "TempVarName
```

I try to limit my use of them, as it becomes hard to manage. I am always careful about when I set the values and I ensure that they are removed after I am finished with them to avoid confusion or issues with values persisting when they shouldn't.